# Как вызвать функцию из существующей библиотеки (.so)

Tags: linux, c, gcc, библиотека

Здравствуйте покажите пожалуйста приметы как можно воспользоваться функциями

мой пример почему-то не работает

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void (*lib_func)();

int call_library()
{
   void     *handle  = NULL;
   lib_func  func    = NULL;
   handle = dlopen("libtemp.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
   if (handle == NULL)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open lib: %s\n", dlerror());
       return -1;
   }
   func = dlsym(handle, "test");

   if (func == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Unable to get symbol\n");
      return -1;
   }

   func("aaa","bbb");
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("ok!\n");
    call_library();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: нужно вызвать функцию test с параметрами из библиотеки libtemp.so

Comment: А почему тип функции без параметров тогда делаете?

Answer (score 1):

> Как вызвать функцию из существующей библиотеки (.so)

Еcли понимать Ваш вопрос буквально, то то, что Вы написали - это стрельба из пушки по воробьям. Зачем такие сложности?!

Вам нужно просто вызвать функцию *test()* из библиотеки "libtemp.so" ? Ну так и скажите об этом компилятору напрямую:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void *test() // Если она определена в dlfcn.h, то - не нужно.

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("ok!\n");
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

А при линковке укажите свою библиотеку:

```
gcc -o main main.c -ltemp.so
```

Проблема может возникнуть только с поиском этой so-шки линкером. Если она НЕ лежит в стандартном пути поиска библиотек, то добавьте этот путь явно. Например, если so-шка расположена в той-же директории, что и *main,c*, то добавтьте ключик -L. ТОЧКА - обозначение текущей директории.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, а компилятор все равно ругается но уже другая ошибка 

`
gcc -L. -o main main.c -ltemp
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘test’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     test("aaa","bbb");
     ^~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/Scrt1.o: неопределённая ссылка на символ «__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.4»
//lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: @Aleksey Первое. Сообщение *implicit declaration of function ‘test’* означает, что в тексте программы есть вызов функции *test*, но нигде (ни в самой программе, ни в h-файлах) нет объявления этой функции. И ликер не знает, как её линковать. Второе. Насколько я понял по сообщениям, у вас кросс-компиляция?  Тогда всё несколько сложнее... Рекомендую Вам как-то перефтормулировать вопрос и дать больше информации.